# Golf this AP CS Java FRQ - Duplicate Sums of Arrays in 2D Array

Tags: code-golf, tips, java

In preparation for the AP Computer Science AP Test (Java), our teacher has been giving us FRQs from previous years for practice.

My friend and I were golfing this during class today and got it as short as we could, but I'd like to see if there are any shorter solutions any of you can come up with.

Rules:

- You must use the predefined method headers, method names, and parameter names.
- You do not have to specify imports.
- All code is to be written in Java.
- No external libraries

Information:

**Part A**

Given an array of type `int`, write a method that returns the sum of the elements of the array.

```
public int arraySum(int[] arr)
{
    /*Implementation to be written in part A*/
}
```

Now, write the implementation for the method `arraySum`.

**Part B**

Given a 2D array of type `int`, write a method that returns a 1-dimensional `int` array containing the sums of each row of the given 2-dimensional array. You must use `arraySum` but may assume it works properly regardless of what you put for part A.

```
public int[] array2dSum(int[] arr2d)
{
    /*Implementation to be written in part B*/
}
```

Now, write the impmenetation for the method `array2dSum`.

**Part C**

Given a 2D array of type `int`, write a method that returns whether or not the sums of the rows of the array are *diverse*, meaning the array contains no duplicate sums. You must use `array2dSum` but may assume it works properly regardless of what you put for part A.

```
public boolean isDiverse(int[] arr2d)
{
    /*Implementation to be written in part C*/
}
```

Now, Write the implementation for the method `isDiverse`.

---

Here's what I have:

**A** - 31 chars

```
return IntStream.of(arr).sum();
```

**B** - 59 chars

```
return Stream.of(arr2d).mapToInt(x->arraySum(x)).toArray();
```

**C** - 86 chars

```
int[]h=array2dSum(arr2d);return IntStream.of(h).distinct().toArray().length==h.length;
```

---

Test Inputs:

`arraySum(new int[] {1, 2, 3})` returns 6

`array2dSum(new int[][] {{1,2},{3,4}})` returns {3,7}

`isDiverse(new int[][] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}})` returns true

`isDiverse(new int[][] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{1,2,3},{7,8,9}})` returns false

Comment: Welcome to the site but in my humble opinion this is too specific. Asking for answers in one language particularly Java which is not particularly golfable (again in my humble opinion) will not get a great response. Maybe try to make the question a bit more open?

Comment: Shouldn't your test case for `array2dSum()` return `{3,7}` ?

Comment: @ElPedro Questions like this are on-topic. The goal is essentially tips, not a challenge.

Comment: @mbomb007 - thanks for the clarification but that is not how I understood it. "Tips for golfing in XXXX language" I understand are on topic but not specific questions that specify a language. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Comment: He already listed his shortest solutions, so it's essentially a tips question. Asking for tips for a specific golf is acceptable, though chat may be a better place to ask. He does not yet have enough rep to post a chat message, though.

Comment: Point taken. Not my kind of question and it wasn't me that downvoted so I guess I'll leave it at that. Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: This question is also a [golf-course](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/56656).  Which are disallowed in most cases.  This particular question seems like a golf course with little interaction and should probably be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is [a golf-course with little interaction](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/56656)

Comment: @WheatWizard - I wasn't aware of golf-course but it pretty well sums up what I was thinking.

Comment: @WheatWizard I understand about golf courses but I didn't want to post a separate question for each part since I thought that would be spam and obnoxious. I also included my shortest solutions so people wouldn't think I was simply asking for someone to do a homework problem or something.

Comment: @WheatWizard also if it wasn't clear I'm not doing it like a golf course where you have to do all 3 parts for an answer, I just wanted to see if anybody could get this any shorter in any of the parts at all

Comment: @Targz - myself I wasn't meaning to be in any way insulting. It's just that questions here usually leave things open to Python/JavaScript/AnyOtherLanguages programmers to also submit an answer unless they are questions asking for tips in a specific language but not usually with a specific question/challenge. Perhaps if you posted this in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) we could help improve the question. Maybe then you would get your Java answer and maybe some interesting answers in Ruby or Perl or other languages.

Comment: "*Given a 2D array of type `int`*" I would expect to see `int[][]` in the signature.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just copied the wording of the original problem